# Laravel Mimetypes Validation Always False

Tags: laravel, validation, mime-types

I am uploading a file and want to check it matches the following:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return ['file' => 'required|mimetypes:
                                    application/vnd.ms-excel,
                                    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,
                                    application/pdf,
                                    text/plain,
                                    text/csv,
                                    csv,
                                    txt,
                                    text/tsv,
                                    image/jpeg,
                                    image/png,
                                    image/svg+xml,
                                    image/tiff,
                                    video/x-msvideo,
                                    video/mpeg
                                    |max:12345678'];
}
```

However, it **always** return "`The file must be a file of type: application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/pdf, text/plain, text/csv, csv, txt, text/tsv, image/jpeg, image/png, image/svg+xml, image/tiff, video/x-msvideo, video/mpeg.`"

The mimetype guessing seems right. For instance, I tried to upload `foobar.csv`

```
$request->file->getMimeType() // text/plain
```

but yet, it still returns `The file must be a file of type [...]`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, have added 'application/octet-stream' as per [RFC 2616 7.2.1](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec7.html#sec7).

```
public function rules()
    {
        return ['file' => 'required|mimetypes:
                                    application/vnd.ms-excel,
                                    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,
                                    application/pdf,
                                    text/plain,
                                    text/csv,
                                    application/octet-stream,
                                    csv,
                                    txt,
                                    text/tsv,
                                    image/jpeg,
                                    image/png,
                                    image/svg+xml,
                                    image/tiff,
                                    video/x-msvideo,
                                    video/mpeg
                                    |max:12345678'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that `mimetypes` are specified as a string. In the string I added new lines for code clarity, which were interpreted as such. When I removed them to have everything in one line it worked:

```
return [
    'file' => 'required|mimetypes:application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,application/pdf,application/octet-stream,text/plain,text/csv,csv,txt,text/tsv,image/jpeg,image/png,image/svg+xml,image/tiff,video/x-msvideo,video/mpeg|max:12345678'
];
```